# Running powershell commands from c# not recognizing the command?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have this snippet of code:

```
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        var ipAddress = target_ip.Text;
        var padName = pad_name.Text;

        txtLogs.AppendText($"Initializing bootstrapping process for {padName}");
        ps.AddCommand($"knife bootstrap windows winrm.......
```

This command works find when typing it in normally in the powershell window. When I do this via C#, it says the command isn't recognized. What else do I need to do?

Comment: `ps.AddCommand(...` -> `ps.AddScript(...`

Comment: Mathias, that looks like what I want. Can you explain the parameters of the AddCommand portion? Is it just "knife" in the add command and the rest in the script portion?

Comment: No I'm suggesting you literally replace AddCommand with AddScript

Comment: Thanks, it worked!